# Сопоставление данных из двух model

Tags: java, html, mvc, thymeleaf

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность на стороне fronted с помощью thymeleaf сопоставлять данные из двух моделей. Допустим есть model news, и есть model user у каждого есть свои поля, и у них есть общее поле у news - это author_id, а у user - это user_id. И мне надо сделать так, чтобы эти два поля сопоставлялись и для новости например с author_id = 2 доставалось поле login из пользователя с user_id = 2.
Извиняюсь, за возможно размытый вопрос, в комментариях могу объяснить детали.

Comment: На стороне frontend? Это в браузере что ли? Там java нет.

Comment: да, там есть thymeleaf, просто model то создается в джаве, поэтому не знаю даже уместен ли тег java тут.

Comment: Thymeleaf это шаблонизатор, он работает только на сервере, он готовит страницу для браузера и после эта страница едет с сервера в браузер.

Comment: То есть если вам надо что то делать в браузере, вам надо javascript или там typescript.

Comment: да, значит на стороне сервера

Comment: thymeleaf  - шаблонизатор, бекенд у вас на Java. это значит , что у вас есть классы news и user. сделайте дто и отдавайте е на фронт, а нужную логику напишите на джаве , используйте меппер. это вполне типичная задача для бекенда